# Can ELBs be used to route traffic to other hosted services by URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Let's say I have web services at `www.mydomain.com` and `something.anotherdomain.com` (a hosted SaaS, for example). I want to set up a router on, say, `xyz.mydomain.com` to send HTTP traffic to `something.anotherdomain.com` if the URL path starts with `/prefix`, and to `www.mydomain.com` otherwise. Is this something ELB can be configured to do? It seems to encourage you to target by IP, but lets say that `something.anotherdomain.com` doesn't provide a static IP for use with this.

As concrete examples, I'd like requests to map:

```
xyz.mydomain.com/prefix/heythere -> something.anotherdomain.com/prefix/heythere
xyz.mydomain.com/blahblah -> www.mydomain.com/prefix/heythere
```

Explicit question: is ELB the appropriate product for this routing, and if so how can it be configured?

Answer (score 1):

No. Load Balancers cannot forward traffic to a **Domain name**.

From [Target Groups for Your **Application** Load Balancers - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html):

> The following are the possible target types:
>
> - `instance`: The targets are specified by instance ID.
> - `ip`: The targets are IP addresses.
> - `lambda`: The target is a Lambda function.

What you describe sounds like a `CNAME` DNS record. This allows you to say "When resolving Domain A, restart the domain name resolution using Domain B". You can configure `CNAME` records in **Amazon Route 53**. This is commonly done for things like "treat requests for `company1.com` as a request for `company2.com`".

Comment: As I understand it DNS configurations and Route 53 in particular aren't able to do this based on URL contents / path though?

Comment: Correct. It will work where you are keeping the same path (`xyz.mydomain.com/prefix/heythere -> something.anotherdomain.com/prefix/heythere`) but not where the path is changing (`xyz.mydomain.com/blahblah -> www.mydomain.com/prefix/heythere`) because only the domain name is managed by DNS. Another option is to configure the web server on the source system to redirect users to the destination system using HTTP redirects.